# How do i get a list of classes in .NET

Tags: c#, reflection

I tried `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(@"path\System.Core.dll")` and ReflectionOnlyLoad but i got exceptions and errors. How do i properly get all the namespaces/classes in an assembly?

For example i got this exception.

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can reference System.Core then

```
    List<string> namespaces = new List<string>();

    var refs = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();

    foreach (var rf in refs) {
        if (rf.Name == "System.Core")
        {
            var ass = Assembly.Load(rf);
            foreach (var tp in ass.GetTypes())
            {
                if (!namespaces.Contains(tp.Namespace))
                {
                    namespaces.Add(tp.Namespace);
                    Console.WriteLine(tp.Namespace);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If you cannot, you will need to attach to the AssemblyResolve event of the CurrentDomain and load all assemblies of types that System.Core.dll uses when loading the dll.

Answer (score 3):

To load an assembly and then get a list of all types:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("System.Core.dll");
Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
```

Unfortunately this will throw an exception if *any* of the types exposed cannot be loaded, and sometimes this load failure cannot be avoided.  In this case however the thrown exception contains a list of all types that were successfully loaded and so we can just do this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("System.Core.dll");

Type[] types;
try
{
    types = assembly.GetTypes();
}
catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
{
    types = ex.Types;
}
```

This will give you a list of all types, including interfaces, structs, enums etc... (If you want just the classes then you can filter that list).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection) to your question.
I do not need to copy & paste it here for you, it might be **greener** to save space rather that copying code from the other thread.  :-)

Comment: Have you read the thread? Try to scroll down and you will see your answer there.

Comment: The answer that looks like it may work has `CurrentDomain_ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve` which i cant figure out and its taking a bit to google but Marino has already showed me the solution (which is different from all those answers). None of those answers use GetReferencedAssemblies. Also i found `LoadFrom` works which also none of those answer has....

Comment: Ah yes I did not look because the question did not mention it... I'm using the Assembly resolve in one of my loaders: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708456/register-c-com-object-without-having-a-real-file-for-regasm but assembly resolve seemed a bit more complex than needed for this case. It is only needed if you cannot reference what you want to reflect...

Comment: Ah yes, then do not mind the answer, you might save space too.

Comment: @Marino yes, loading was the problem. None of those answers mention the functions i required. Anyways this Q is done.